# How to reload a vaadin tabpage from another one

Tags: java, tabs, actionlistener, vaadin

I'm using a `tabcontainer` in my webpage. In one of the `tabpages`, I'm adding some data to a table. In another `tabpage` I'm dynamically generating `buttons` according to same table. However, the inserted or deleted changes are not shown in that page; there are no new buttons for new values or disappeared buttons for deleted records. I'm using `Vaadin Push` both as an `annotation` and as manually. I'm also refilling the table on tabpage change:

```
public MainTabContainer(){
//...
    tabshtMain.addSelectedTabChangeListener(new SelectedTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectedTabChange(SelectedTabChangeEvent event) {
            event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab().setEnabled(true);
            event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab().requestRepaintAll();

             if (event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab() == steril) {
                steril.fillTables();
                tabshtMain.markAsDirty();
                steril.markAsDirty();
                getUI().push();                 
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And here is the code sample where I generate buttons for the records in class of tabpage:

```
private MHorizontalLayout buildMHorizontalLayout_3() {
        horizontalLayout_3 = new MHorizontalLayout();
        horizontalLayout_3.setImmediate(true);
        horizontalLayout_3.setWidth("100.0%");
        horizontalLayout_3.setHeight("-1px");
        horizontalLayout_3.setMargin(false);

        for (StrMachine strMchn : listGrp.keySet()) {
            MButton btnMakine = new MButton();
            btnMchn.setImmediate(true);
            btnMchn.setWidth("80px");
            btnMchn.setHeight("80px");
            btnMchn.setCaption(Icon.CREDIT_CARD.variant(IconVariant.SIZE_4X));

            btnMchn.setHtmlContentAllowed(true);
            btnMchn.setId(strMchn.getCode());
            btnMchn.addClickListener(btnMchnClickListener);

            horizontalLayout_3.addComponent(btnMchn);
            horizontalLayout_3.setComponentAlignment(btnMakine, new Alignment(48));

        }

        return horizontalLayout_3;
        }
```

To solve the issue I've made controls 'immediate' and called requestRepaintAll() bu they didn't help. Only refreshing page is working though.

Sorry for my language and missing jargons of sof. If you have any solutions or suggestions for the problem, please advise me.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use Push? The building of the new Buttons is triggered directly from a UI thread, and not a background thread, correct?

Comment: Yes, the buttons are built from UI thread, not from a background thread. And I use Push to update tabpage from tabsheet. It also doesn't work when I don't call push manually.

Comment: Push is only needed when you have a server side thread updating your UI. What do you mean by "Only refreshing page is working though", does pressing F5 show the correct page content?

Comment: I use Push because i need to update the content from server-side. Because I insert a new row to machines table. And generate a button for each machine in the other tabpage. So refreshing page by pressing F5 is useful. My question is there any other way -maybe with background thread- to refresh the tabpage or tabcontainer's content on selectedtabchange.

Comment: How is the new row inserted in the machines table? If it is done via the same vaadin session, then it should work without the need for push. You need push, when you have things that change on serverside, without interaction from the same vaadin session.